# Azure Template Fails when deployed

Tags: azure

I'm trying to deploy the azure template located here 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/sharepoint-three-vm/

Everything appears to be working fine accept the first three variables shown in the screen shot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGp5p.png)

Can someone help shed some light on the problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says it all.

[image]

Replace the image size, or replace the region you're trying to run your PowerShell at.

**Edit**: instead of trying to guess your way into finding the right VM size and the appropriate location to host it, take a look at the [Azure Products by Region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/) page. All the VM sizes are there with their available locations.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't see that. I will change that and try again. Will keep you posted. Cheer

Comment: Which region do you select? Maybe you could try to check if you have permission to create a Standard_DS1 size VM in the same region on Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi @Walter-MSFT, I selected ukwest as the region. I have tried many regions and I still get the same error. I also tried Standard_DS1 and got the same error

Comment: @Walter-MSFT, I changed the VM size to  Standard_AS1 and I got the following error message \"Storage account type Premium_LRS is not supported for VM size Standard_A

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I changed the VM size to A1, not AS1.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT,  I changed the region to Central US and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: The UK region is new and currently only supports the newer DV2 machines, it does not have the older v1 machines. So if you want to deploy there you need to use Standard_DS1_v2

Comment: DS-series is not supported by UK region.  For more information about products available by regions, please refer to the  article. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/